# virtualbox support for directx 10

Tags: virtualbox, directx-10

I have VirtualBox installed on a Mac and I'm running Windows 7 in it. 
I need to have directX 10 to run an application. 
The best I've managed to get is directX 9.

Is it available?
I have found on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox_Extras
that I could use wine3d, but the note says that it only works on Windows 7 RC guests AFAIK,
what is that ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it's saying that you need the Windows 7 Release Candidate in order to be sure it will work (RC = Release Candidate). I took the AFAIK part to mean "As Far As I Know". I have a similar issue to you, but I can't see why something would work on the RC but not on the standard Windows 7 so I'm going to try it anyway...